# Which way i should connect My Android Device with ASP.NET Web API and Signal R

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, architecture, signalr, signalr-hub

I have an Android App which i had currently connected with Asp.NET Web API and Now i have to implement SignalR 2 Stuff in the Web API. Now should i connect my Android App with Web API and connect Web API with SignalR (does it give me unique ConnectionID for every different request obtained so that i can check which devices are currently connected) or I have to connect SignalR and then Connect my SignalR with Web API for database work. Which flow i should follow as i want an immediate response as well as persistance of data.

Comment: And what will be the URL of the SignalR to Get connected

Comment: for eg if URL of the site is http://www.asdf.com

Comment: then What will be url of Android app to be used